# How to send static html as an email content in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#

I am sending an static html with some dynamic content to user email id using c# and JQuery.
Below is the JavaScriot file from where I am calling th method SendEmail.

$(".EmailInvoice").click(function () {

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: siteUrl + '/invoiceEmail.asmx/SendEmail',
        data: JSON.stringify({  }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function (data, status) {              

        },
        failure: function (data) {

        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

Below is the invoiceEmail.asmx file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Hosting;

namespace meltwish
{
    /// <summary>
/// Summary description for invoiceEmail
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
 [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class invoiceEmail : System.Web.Services.WebService
{


    public static string PopulateBody(string userName, string title, string url, string description)
    {
        string body = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/EmailTemplate.html")))
        {
            body = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        body = body.Replace("{UserName}", userName);
        body = body.Replace("{Title}", title);
        body = body.Replace("{Url}", url);
        body = body.Replace("{Description}", description);
        return body;
    }

    public static void SendHtmlFormattedEmail(string recepientEmail, string subject, string body)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
        mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"]);
        mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        mailMessage.Body = body;
        mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(recepientEmail));
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Host"];
        smtp.EnableSsl = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnableSsl"]);
        System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
        NetworkCred.UserName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UserName"];
        NetworkCred.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"]);
        smtp.Send(mailMessage);
    }

    //object sender, EventArgs e
   [WebMethod]
    public static string SendEmail()
    {

         //string body = this.PopulateBody("John",
        string body = PopulateBody("John",
            "Fetch multiple values as Key Value pair in ASP.Net AJAX AutoCompleteExtender",
            "http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Fetch-multiple-values-as-Key-Value-pair-" +
            "in-ASP.Net-AJAX-AutoCompleteExtender.aspx",
            "Here Mudassar Ahmed Khan has explained how to fetch multiple column values i.e." +
            " ID and Text values in the ASP.Net AJAX Control Toolkit AutocompleteExtender"
            + "and also how to fetch the select text and value server side on postback");
        SendHtmlFormattedEmail("wajedkh@gmail.com", "New article published!", body);
        //this.SendHtmlFormattedEmail("wajedkh@gmail.com", "New article published!", body);
        return "sajjad";
    }


}
}
```

This is the HTMl file that is added to the project. The name is EmailTemplate.html

```
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


   <!-- Server CDN Files -- Start -->
    <!--<link class="temp" href="http://klcdn.meltwish.com/styles/store/1.0.2/store.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
    <link href="http://localhost:60339/styles/store/1.0.2/store.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>

   <img src = "http://www.aspsnippets.com/images/Blue/Logo.png" /><br /><br />
<div style = "border-top:3px solid #22BCE5">&nbsp;</div>
<span style = "font-family:Arial;font-size:10pt">
Hello <b>{UserName}</b>,<br /><br />
A new article has been published on ASPSnippets.<br /><br />
<a style = "color:#22BCE5" href = "{Url}">{Title}</a><br />
{Description}
<br /><br />
Thanks<br />
ASPSnippets
</span>
</body>
</html>
```

This i have added in the Web.Config file.

```
<appSettings>
      <add key="Host" value="smtp.gmail.com"/>
      <add key="EnableSsl" value="true"/>
      <add key="UserName" value="hussainsajjad9991@gmail.com"/>
     <add key="Password" value="xxxxx"/>
      <add key="Port" value="587"/>
</appSettings>
```

Actually whenever I have trying to call the javascript ajax method it is going to the error content.

Help me....

Comment: what's the error? is it 5XX!!

Answer (score 0):

Following C# Code Work For me

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
 public static string SendEmail()
 {
  using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("From", "To"))
  {
    mm.Subject = "Subject ";
    mm.Body = "<html><head></head><body> Content</body></html>"; 
    mm.IsBodyHtml=true;                                                              
   SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
   smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
   smtp.EnableSsl = false;
   NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("From", "password");
                   smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                   smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
                   smtp.Port = 587;
                   smtp.Timeout = 2000000;
                   smtp.Send(mm);
                   return "Success";  
   }
}
```

And Use Ajax Code

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
     url: siteUrl + '/invoiceEmail.aspx/SendEmail',
     data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    datatype: "jsondata",
    async: "true",
    success: function (t) {  alert(t);  },
   error: function (t) {  alert(t);    }  })
```

Comment: Actually when I am calling my SendEmail() from Ajax, it is giving an alert for error.

Comment: Change    data: JSON.stringify({  }),   to    data: "{}",

Comment: if no parameter then no need  JSON.stringify

Comment: There is no parameter

Comment: when i calling the function SendEmail() of the .aspx file from Ajax then the error part is executing with an alert .

    error: function () {
                alert("error");
            }

Comment: Use my ajax and C# Code it work for me hope it will work for you  Or  use   " error: function (t) { alert(t); } "  you get Exact error code